# What does "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem [...]" mean when my question is closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I'm curious what the phrase *"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer"* means.

I'm talking about the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486880/updating-window-borders-when-dragging-from-the-finder).

It talks about a very specific issue, and it even gives an example of what I'm looking for. So how much detail is needed or what specific detail is required to satisfy the community?

Or maybe this is just a unified reason that is used almost everywhere because other reasons are not applicable?

Could someone please shed some light on it?

Comment: It's very broad because you just describe an effect and ask how to implement it without even mentioning your stack. There are *thousands* of ways to do this. Perhaps more. Without a specific context, it's impossible to say how to do it.

Comment: So you already have the code written, compiled and running for an app with an Window that accepts drag and drop events for files?

Comment: I'll remove my comments shortly as I don't want to litter this question with off-topic rambling - but I just don't see the distinction between "show your work" and "put in some effort". But by EFFORT I mean "give a good description of the problem", or "show your working", or hell, "give us an example". Perhaps I should be clearer in future. Questions that just say, "how do I do x" without any background context or conceivable research to me should always be closable.

Comment: @Lewis: Under "Too Broad" or "Questions asking for troubleshooting help must include..."

Comment: I think the argument here is over  the same thing. Ultimately the question doesn't have any effort in terms of coding put in. As Robert says, that itself is not a close reason, though - at best, it's a downvote reason. However, the no effort *also* means that there is nothing people can work with. Having code would help people answer. In this case, the question is too broad and *effort* could have narrowed it down. So both "no effort" isn't a closing reason by itself but *in this case* it would have aided answers and without it, there is very little to aid them.

Comment: *I did some research on how to implement it, but I didn't get any meaningful explanation.* Was the information you found not helpful or were you unable to find any information on the subject at all? Either way, "I didn't understand [article], [documentation]" or "I used search terms [x], [y], and [z] and found nothing." is still useful information for people trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, your programming question is quite specific, and I would imagine it has a single, canonical answer that could be answered in a short paragraph or two.  The problem is that you haven't brought your prior research with you.

There's nothing wrong with asking "how do you do [something]," especially if your question is specific enough.  The problem is that many askers expect to get a complete solution while providing incomplete information, which either requires answers that are too long, or protracted question-answer sessions with the OP to determine what they actually need.

Hence, our requirement that you "show your work."  That's what *"please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer"* means.

To prove the point, I did [a quick Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=objective+c+drag+and+drop+border+mouse), which resulted in [this article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1016-drag-and-drop-tutorial-for-macos) that outlines the broad brush strokes of what you want to do under the heading "Tell the User What’s Happening."

Comment: **Downvoters:** I personally couldn't care less whether you explain your downvote or not, as this is how I already moderate anyway.  The OP could possibly benefit from an explanation, however.

Comment: I understand. The problem might lie in the fact that I'm an ESL person. But for me much clearer would be to say "Please explain what you tried and what didn't work in order to get a proper answer". The explanation given is inself too broad to have a meaning.

Comment: now in terms of the question - I'm just a beginner with OSX/Cocoa/Objective-C way of programming. I did some research on how to implement it, but I didn't get any meaningful explanation. On top of that I thought that this would be handled by the OS itself and I wouldn't need to do anything there.

Comment: Did you read the article I linked?

Comment: I will read it later. Thank you for the link. I hope I will find the explanation and the code sample I'm looking for. If I have any more questions I will create another thread. Thx once again.